# Coordinate expression of left invariant vector fields on $SU(1,1)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'm trying to work out some differential geometry of the matrix Lie group $SU(1,1)$.
It is the group of $2\times 2$ complex matrices such that:

$$
(U^{*})^{T}\eta U=\eta
$$
where:

$$
\eta=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 &-1\end{array}\right)
$$
From this it follows:

$$
U=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\alpha & \beta \\ \overline{\beta} & \overline{\alpha}\end{array}\right)
$$
and:

$$
\alpha\overline{\alpha} - \beta\overline{\beta}=1
$$
This means there are three free parameters, one possible choice is $(\omega,\gamma,\theta)$ such that:

$$
U=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \exp(\imath\omega)\cosh(\theta) & \exp(\imath\gamma)\sinh(\theta) \\ \exp(-\imath\gamma)\sinh(\theta)  & \exp(-\imath\omega)\cosh(\theta) \end{array}\right)
$$
Where $U$ is the image of $g\in SU(1,1)$ through its embedding $i$ in $GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$.
Now the coordinates $(\omega,\gamma,\theta)$ do not allow me to find the elements of a basis in $T_{e}SU(1,1)$ as derivatives of the coordinate curves because the coordinate curve of $\gamma$ does not pass on the identity element $e$.
I thus tried another way and found that the defining condition of $SU(1,1)$ and the properties of the exponential map allow to write the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ as:

$$
A: (A^{*})^{T}\eta -\eta A= \;\;\;Tr(A)=0
$$ 
and thus to find three matrices:

$$
A_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \imath \\ -\imath & 0\end{array}\right)
$$
$$A_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
A_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}  \imath & 0 \\ 0 &-\imath\end{array}\right)
$$

It turns out that:

$$
A_{2}=(i_{*})_{e}\frac{d c_{2}(t)}{dt}\left|_{t=0}\right.\;\;\;c_{2}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}c_{2}^{\omega}(t)=0\\c_{2}^{\theta}(t)=t\\c_{2}^{\gamma}(t)=0\end{array}\right.
$$

$$
A_{3}=(i_{*})_{e}\frac{d c_{3}(t)}{dt}\left|_{t=0}\right.\;\;\;c_{3}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}c_{3}^{\omega}(t)=t\\c_{3}^{\theta}(t)=0\\c_{3}^{\gamma}(t)=0\end{array}\right.
$$

My question is: what curve $c_{1}(t)$ through $e$ is such that its derivative at $e$  is $A_{1}=(i_{*})_{e}\frac{dc_{1}(t)}{dt}\left|_{t=0}\right.$?

I need to know it because I'm interested in the left invariant vector fields on $SU(1,1)$.

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: I've found a way to exhibit the left and right-invariant vector fields that do not use the curves $c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}$. I will write it down as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I believe $$\gamma(t)= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
2e^{-iu}-e^{-2iu} & \sqrt{2}e^{2iu}-\sqrt{2}e^{iu}  \\
\sqrt{2}e^{-2iu}-\sqrt{2}e^{-iu} & 2e^{iu}-e^{2iu}  \\
 \end{array} \right)$$
will work. Here $u=t/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thank You for the answer. However the curve $\gamma(t)$ I need should be such that at $\gamma(0)=e$, where $e$ is the identity element in $SU(1,1)$, unfortunately the curve You suggested is such that $\gamma(0)\neq e$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, corrected.

You don't need them for left invariant fields, because if $x \in \mathfrak{gl}(n)$ then left invariant field generated by $x$ is $X(g)=gx$ and that is true for any subgroup of $GL(n)$

Comment: Oh, that is not correct again. I need to do the computations once more)

Comment: hope it will work now)